# Double emails send by lambda function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I have a problem with async, I think I don't understand the principle well enough.
I am trying to send a message to my inbox from a lambda function, but every time I get the same message twice. Can anybody explain what is going wrong or how to change the code to only send one message?

This is my function:

```
function sendToTopic(error){
    var sns = new AWS.SNS(); 
    let eventText = 'Error message: \n' + error;

    var params = {
        Message: eventText, 
        Subject: "Test SNS From Lamba",
        TopicArn: 'arn'
    };
    console.log(params);
    
    let promise =  sns.publish(params, function onPublish(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.error("Unable to send to Topic. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
        console.log('succes:' + data);
    }).promise();
    return promise;
}
```

This is my handler:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let promise = sendToTopic("error");
    await promise;
}
```

Comment: It seems that your question is about AWS SDK, not CDK. Does CDK come into play here?

Comment: sorry typo i will change the tag

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when the execution rate of the lambda is high, SNS don't handle them very well. For that, it triggers Delivery Retry Policies and I think when the same message appears it delivers multiple times.

Quick Resolution you can try (not 100% sure): Under your SNS topic you've to check delivery retry policies and change `numRetries` parameter to 0 and try.
It may help!